# Actions from Object table

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

Is there a way to launch actions from an object table somehow ?

I have a URL type of column in my object table and ideally I would like to open the URL in a new tab when clicking on the URL (this I achieved) **plus** launching an action at the same time.

Indeed, I would like to update a property of that object when that click is performed, for which I have created a functions-backed action, ready to be used. My problem is I can't launch it when I would like (i.e. on that URL click).

Thanks